# Deploying new react apps built with webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, amazon-ecs, sticky-session

I have small edge case where my apps are failing in production.
let me try to explain the scenerio.

i am building many react applications with webpack. the static assets get copied to a single nodejs app, with different routes rendering different react apps. 
i use `codeship` to build my application code into a docker image. and `aws ecs` to deploy it

here is a typical scenario when i try to deploy new changes to production/staging.

**TAG1** => existing running application on ecs.

route `/dashboard/`

renders `/dashboard/index.html` which has static refrences as

`/static/app/dashboard/main.a1.js`. a1 is chunk hash generated by webpack

`/static/app/dashboard/homepage.a2.js.`

**TAG2** => new app which is deployed/deploying currently

route `/dashboard/`

renders `/dashboard/index.html` which has static refrences as

`/static/app/dashboard/main.b1.js`. b1 is chunk hash generated by webpack

`/static/app/dashboard/homepage.b2.js.`

**Now Chunk hash change because my application code has change. also its a new docker image this time**

**I have also enabled sticky session with 1 minute duration on ALB**

now the issue is after deployment i have a time window of about 1-2 minutes where static assets start giving me `404`. after 1-2 minutes app stabilizes and things start working fine.

it could be because of the following issues.

1. old container requests are going to new container because sticky session has expired. and user has not refreshed the page.
2. new container requests are going to old container because sticky session is not working.

in any case i am getting 404 for the applications.

i want to know what can be done to avoid this scenerio.